# Ignored files showing up as untracked

Tags: git

The whole problem started when I moved the project to a folder inside the repo to keep everything organized. I want to keep tokens out of git scope

I have a `.gitgnore` as follows:

```
bot/__pycache__/*
bot/token
bot/staging_token
*.pyc
```

By this I assume that both token and staging_token shouldn't be tracked.
Despite this, git status shows:

```
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    bot/staging_token
    bot/token
```

I've already done `git rm -r --cached .` and than `git add .`. After that both tokens are still added to staging area.

In order to test it I also added bot/* to `.gitgnore` and than repeated `git rm  -r --cached .` . output:

```
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    .gitgnore
    deleted:    Dockerfile
    deleted:    bot/main.py
    deleted:    bot/portfolio.py
    deleted:    bot/reply_messages.py
    deleted:    bot/requirements.txt
    deleted:    bot/telegram_commands.txt
    deleted:    bot/telegram_interface.py
    deleted:    bot/ticker.py
    deleted:    bot/yfinance.py
    deleted:    readme.md

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .gitgnore
    Dockerfile
    bot/
    readme.md
```

and git add .. And this was the output:

```
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
       (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
        (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    modified:   .gitgnore
    new file:   bot/staging_token
    new file:   bot/token
```

What should I do to keep ignored files out of untracked?

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows the filename as `.gitgnore`.  It has to be `.gitignore`.